# NullPointer exception at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm seeing a weird exception in Android Support Library - the stack trace is below. Any ideas what could be causing this? I'm unable to reproduce the exception on any of my devices, but there seem to be quite a few visible in the Google Play DevConsole.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1133)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1171)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:582)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can we see where in the code this is thrown?

Comment: I'm learning about this riht now but I think this info is not enough?
The problems I have had with Fragments so far have included null pointers exception and in all of them is that the parent (main activity) Context,activity or view passed is null becasue the fragment is not attached to the activity (usually after resume) try looking there and.. more info please :)

Comment: that's all I have as far as error reports go ... I'd love to have more.

Comment: Experiencing the same when a fragment is removed that has been added to another fragment via its child fragment manager. Pretty reproducible :(

Comment: @LambergaR, Have you found the answer for this? I'm having the same issue in X10a devices(only)?

Comment: I know how to reproduce this exception on my app using `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`: navigate to the `ViewPager`, press home button, click the app icon to start it, navigate to the `ViewPager` again. But I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: @LambergaR : did you find the solution for this exception ?. I am also getting the same exception and unable to reproduce it easily.

Answer (score 1):

try check stack fragments in time rotate screen for example in onResume.

Comment: We only support portrait orientation, so it isn't (shouldn't be) associated with that.

Comment: may be problem in transfer from active mode to pause?

Comment: might be, but I'm not able to replicate the damn thing

Comment: You should share the code with us. Otherwise we can't help you