# NullPointerException with fragments using support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, google-play-games

I am the developer of a game currently available on Google Play Store. I've been using Google Play Games since it released. The game had Scoreboards and achievements.

Some days ago, I decided to implement turn based multiplayer for it, but I'm getting an error in the support library (it doesn't show any clue of what am I doing wrong in my code) when the user receives a "Google Play Game notification" (This is when you invite someone to play a game, or it's your turn to play etc) and you click on the notification to open the game.

The error seems to happen randomly, sometimes when you click the notification the app crashes and sometimes it does not.

This is the error:

```
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1158)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1201)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:639)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-23 19:57:40.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have setRetainInstance(true)? Think that has been known to cause some issues that look like this.

Comment: No, unless it is set like that by default.

Comment: This might help: [I'm seeing a weird exception in Android Support Library ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394437/nullpointer-exception-at-android-support-v4-app-fragmentmanagerimpl-makeinactive])